# "Отжать" CapsLock с помощью java.awt.Robot

Tags: awt, java

Доброго дня!
Для ввода логина\пароля использую awt.Robot:

```
Robot robot = new Robot();
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK); //turn on
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_W);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_X);
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK); //turn off
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

После выполнения этого куска Капс остаётся нажатым. Как его выключить? Сталкивался кто-нибудь? 
Пробовала тот же самый кейс с нажатием шифта, эффект такой же. Шифт остаётся нажатым.

Comment: `keyRelease`.

Comment: Что keyRelease? В какой момент его использовать? Когда включаем капс или когда выключаем? Оба способа не сработали.

Comment: >> Что keyRelease?

Это метод, который вам нужен.

>> В какой момент его использовать? Когда включаем капс или когда выключаем?

А вы подумайте немного, имя метода то говорящее. А вообще, вам дано, что искать, не поленились бы, да заглянули в документацию.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда вы букву с помощью клавиатуры печатаете вы что делаете? Клавишу нажимаете И отпускаете. В вашем коде вы только нажимаете клавишу, так и оставляя "палец" не ней. Что вы хотите сделать нажимая уже нажатую кнопку?

Вот верный код:

```
...
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);   //нажимаем...
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK); //и отпускаем. Как человек:)
//Сейчас капс включен
...
robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);   //снова нажимаем...
robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK); //и снова отпускаем. 
//Теперь капс выключен
```

Comment: Спасибо, так работает.
По аналогии получается, надо и буквы так же нажимать? :)

Comment: Да, конечно, буквы тоже так.

Comment: @Alex18, буквы-то как раз нажимаются простым keyPress. В любом случае, спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Нажимаются и держаться нажатыми. Деля простой вызов keyPress, вы оставляете ее нажатой. Вот доказательство: http://pastebin.com/tw6JXTnm. Возможно, я не так вас понял.